# How to add a pop-up in the home page of an app using react-native and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a javascript code for a home page in my app. I want to make every user see a pop-up on the screen when they open an app, click a button, and then they can use the app. As well, I need to make sure that once they click the button they do not see that pop-up screen again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncStorage` from facebook to set and retrieve the data. check this out [facebook async storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

**Second approach**

Also, If you are already using redux, you can try to persist-store

For details check [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

For popup, you can use [react native modal library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal).

In order to make the popup not appear again after the button press then you should use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage).

Save a key-value pair when the button is pressed. Before the popup appears, make sure to retrieve the data from the `AsyncStorage` and verify if the value is present.